# rdlc in VS2018 WebApi : The report definition has an invalid target namespace which cannot be upgraded

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, rdlc, reportbuilder

I'm implementing a rdlc report in a basic .net WebApi 2.0.

I have implemented a basic method that run the report and save it in a local folder, just for test.

When I've tried to add a parameter to the report, the webapi method stopped to work and It started to return this message:

**The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded**

I notice that when I added the report parameter, Visual Studio 2017 switched the schema from:

**http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition**

to

**http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition**

In this moment I can view the report in ReportBuilder but If I try to generate it by application I get that message.

Now I'm updating Visual Studio to the last version ( 15.7.3 ) but I don't think it will fix the problem.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I fixed the problem by removing ReportViewer 11.0.0 and by installing ReportViewerControl.WebForms:

**Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Version 140.1000.523**

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating the service, then i need to touch all pages to change referance version to 14 so I have done using the following answer and it worked: 
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548615/1053191)

*Its a temporary solution, if you haven't modify design it will work*