# How can I change the ServerTargetVersion for SSRS rdl

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

My Visual Studio version is 2019.
My ssrs reporting solution properties are set to **SQL Server 2008R2, 2012 or 2014**.
Visual Studio still builds the 2016 Version of my SSRS rdl Reports.

This leads to problems in deployment of the reports.

I know that I can fix the issues with the following post:
[stackoverflow...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272514/the-report-definition-has-an-invalid-target-namespace-rsinvalidreportdefinition/37548615)
But afert every update of a report, the version jumps back to 2016.

I read that the problem is in the ServerTargetVersion of the SSDT but I cant find out how and where to set the the right build version.

I found this [article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/tim/issue-publishing-to-ssrs-2012-with-ssdt-2015/) on setting the Default Deployment Server version.
But in VS2019 I do not see the the option for "Alalyses Service Designer".

Does anyone have walkthrough?
How can I change the ServerTargetVersion?

Answer (score 0):

I think quickest way is to go to the Solution Explorer window, right click on your PROJECT and go to Properties. It will open the deployment window and the very last option should be TargetServerVersion that will allow you to change the Target version.